# How to send a request using intents to playstore to download an application whose package name is mentioned

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am trying to create an app in android studios that will show the icon of the app installed into my app activity. I want to send a request from my app to play store to and install the app in background in the device with out going to play store and show the icon of the installed app in my app

Comment: And I want a pony.  Now what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it. You can only open `PlayStore` app with `package name` parameter and if user wants to do it then he installs the app.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
'final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try {
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}'
```